# why Dangling pointer cannot store any value and why does it throw 0?

Tags: c, dangling-pointer

why can Dangling pointer not store any value and why does it throw 0? As it points to same memory which is freed. why 0 if we try to store some value?

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   int main()
  {
     int *p;
     p=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*5);//allocating memory in heap
     printf("%p\n",p);
     free(p);            //freeing memory
     printf("%p\n",p);   //still pointer same loaction(dangling pointer)
     scanf("%d",p);   // why cant i scan if it is still pointing same location
              // i know memory is delete but why 0 is thrown? 
      printf("%d\n",*p);// i am getting zero here?
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is illegal memory accessing. The address should not be used after freeing.

After deallocating an address, set the pointer to NULL. So that the illegal memory accessing will be eradicated.

Example:

```
  free(p); 
  p=NULL;
```

Comment: Why/how does setting the pointer to `NULL` "solve" illegal memory access?

Comment: @mahendiran.b please understand question before replying ,i am not asking how to avoid dangling pointer rather i am concern why it is throwing 0 as o/p when i try to store value

Comment: @SumitKumar There's no particular reason why it returns 0. Undefined behavior can do literally anything. In your case, it happens to make that memory address store a 0. Nobody can say anything more precise.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant somehow we what to remove the address stored in p after deallocation to prevent illegal use. So if p is set NULL it will be give any undefined behavior. In the above program if we set p=NULL; after free, this line scanf("%d",p);  will cause crash. This is something like standard to avoid human errors.

Comment: Note that the `p = NULL;` trick only works reliably if `p` is the only reference to the freed memory.  If there are other variables that hold the pointer value too, then you've only fixed one source of trouble, not all of them.

Comment: @mahendiran.b "will cause crash" - nope, it *may* cause a crash. You also seem to be confusing observed and defined behavior. So, this is not a guarantee that invalid memory access will be detected.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing the freed memory is undefined behavior. Anything can happen. You got zero this time, and you can get anything next time.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior for reference

Comment: @SumitKumar no, that's wrong. Maybe on your system, with your compiler, with your particular setup of compiler flags it's true, but not in general. "compile it and see" is **not an argument.** Only the abstract behavior as described by the Standard is valid reasoning.

Comment: "..every time.." is treating *observed behavior* and *defined behavior* as synonymous; they're *not*. The language standard specifically calls out writing to an indeterminate address is *undefined behavior*. Just because you see something doesn't make it *defined* by the language standard.